# MapReduce - insert directly into first position of a vector<int> in a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, mapreduce, word-count

currently I am writing a WordCounter (MapReduce).

My implementation of the reduce function looks like:

```
void WordCounter::Reduce(string intermediateWord, vector<int> intermediateLineNr) {
    resultMap.insert(pair<string, vector<int> >(intermediateWord, intermediateLineNr));
    vector<int>& resultLineNr = resultMap[intermediateWord];
    resultLineNr.clear();
    resultLineNr.push_back(intermediateLineNr.size());
} // WordCounter::Reduce
```

I also use a resultMap which is a map with a string and a vectory data component:

```
map<string, vector<int> > WordMap;
```

I use an intermediateMap variable which contains each word and the line numbers where it occurs. Now I want to add each word to the resultMap but instead of the line numbers I would like to add the number of words at the first position of the vector.

Right now I copy the whole intermediateLineNr vector, clear it and insert on the first position the number of words.

Is there any possibility to insert directly into the first position of the specific vector ?

I think there should be an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maybe do not get what you ask but the code you posted does equivalent of that:

```
void WordCounter::Reduce(string intermediateWord, vector<int> intermediateLineNr) 
{
    resultMap[intermediateWord] = vector<int>( 1, intermediateLineNr.size() );
} // WordCounter::Reduce
```

Note that you are passing `vector<int> intermediateLineNr` by value, so there will be copy of the vector made during call. Replace it with `vector<int> const& intermediateLineNr`; it
works as well.

Comment: Thansk, that works fine for me. But i have one question, does the [] operator automatically add the word if it doesn't exist in the map?

Comment: Yes, that is how the behavior is specified

Comment: Yes, map has such operator[] that does add missing elements automatically. Lot of people say that map is confusing because of that.